# How to tell TS Server like all JS codes are in a single file?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, clasp, tsserver

I use `clasp` and VS Code to develop app which runs as Google Apps Script. In Google Apps Script every codes work as if they are written in a single file so the following results error.

a.js

```js
const foo = "foo";
```

b.js

```js
const foo = "bar";
```

It is virtually like:

```js
const foo = "foo";
const foo = "bar";
```

When coding on VS Code I get no error from TS Server but I want it. In other word I want TS Server to treat  all codes are in a single file. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do it, but I am sure that you don't want to do this. It works this way for a reason - it is very hard to read and maintain code with global constants shared between files and no imports. If you want to share values between files, you should export them from one file and import them into the other.

Comment: I know the risk you mentioned but it's Google Apps Script's restriction so with no doubt I need it. Please don't care that sharing global constants is not practical, it's just a sample a.k.a MRE.

Comment: Program code [is uncountable.](https://blog.michael.gr/2023/05/code-is-uncountable.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `tsconfig.json` in the project directory for tsserver to recognize that both files are part of the same project. Create one like:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "types": ["location of /node_modules/@types/google-apps-script"]
  },
  "include": ["./"],
  "exclude": []
}
```

The `tree` should look like

```
.
├── appsscript.json
├── a.js
├── b.js
├── tsconfig.json
```